# Get the sum of numbers from $75$ to $995$ with interval of $5$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm looking for a formula that would help me Get the sum of numbers from $75$ to $995$ with interval of $5$. So it will be $75+80+85+90$ and so on. Please help me.

Comment: There are $\frac{995-75}{5}+1=185$ numbers you want to sum. Can you carry on from here?

Comment: AP could be the solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We start with
$$
S = \sum_{i=0}^N (75 + 5 i)
$$
the first task is to find the upper bound $N$ for $i$. Can you do this?

We then optimize
\begin{align}
S &= 75 \sum_{i=0}^N 1 + 5 \sum_{i=0}^N i \\
&= 75 (N+1) + 5 \frac{(N+1)N}{2} \\
&= (N+1) \left( 75 + \frac{5}{2} N \right) \\
&= \frac{5}{2} N^2 + \left( 75 + \frac{5}{2} \right) N + 75
\end{align}
where we used linearity and then Gauss's formula for the sum of the integers from $1$ to $N$.

Update:
To determine $N$ one looks at the last term of the sum:
$$
75 + 5 N = 995 \iff \\
N = (995 - 75) / 5 = 184
$$
Now it is easy to calculate $S$, or?

Comment: @PalashSharma, have you tried his approach? Really all you need to do is figure out $N$.

Comment: Perhaps you should show your efforts on solving this, for now it seems like you only care for the answer, but obviously you want to learn how to solve this type of problems. Show us what you've tried by editing the post, and we're glad to help at where you're stuck.

Answer (score 2):

You've just described an arithmetic progression.
Formula for finding the sum of AP:

$$ S_n = \frac{n}{2}(a + l)$$
$$ l = a + (n-1)d$$

where $l$= last term, $a =$ first term, $n =$ no. of terms in sequence.

You first find the number of terms in this sequence:

$$995 = a+ (n-1)d= 75 + (n-1)5 $$

$$n=185$$
Now find the sum:
$$ S_n= \frac{185}{2}(75+995) = 98975$$

If you're looking for a formula to do this directly:

$$\text{Sum} = \frac{(d+l -a)(a+l)}{2d} $$

where $a = 75, \ l= 995 \ d = 5, \ \text{Sum} = \text{sum from} \ a \ \text{to} \ l$